# HipHop PHP -- Passing Arguments to Compiled PHP Executable

Tags: php, hiphop

I'm trying to understand the HipHop documentation, but it's not very clear. I have a PHP script I want to compile into an executable with HipHop.

How do I pass arguments to this PHP executable by command line? And how is this received by the PHP script ($_GET['arg']?)

I want to do something like this:
my_compiled_script --variablename="This is the value"

Which is then received by the script as:
$_GET['variablename']

So how does that work?

Comment: Unless Hiphop only builds executables with built-in webserver, you might get cmdline args in `$_SERVER["argv"]` as in regular PHP. Otherwise set `QUERY_STRING=` in the shell to poison `$_GET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with some testing.

As mario said above, the arguments come in exactly the same format as when running PHP: they start at $argv[1] ($argv[0] is empty).